# Populate a div using AJAX and JQUERY one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I have a json file like this:

```
    [
      {
       "name": "Joe"
      },

      {
       "name": "Chloe"
      },

      {
       "name": "DeShawn"
      },

      {
       "name": "Carol"
      },

      {
       "name": "Dane"
      },

      {
       "name": "Samantha"
      },
    ]
```

And I would like to populate the `id="names"` with a `"name"` every time I click the button in the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/action.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h1> Name randomizer </h1>  
        <div id= "container">
            <div id="names">
            </div>
            <button>Next name</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the AJAX request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
   var names = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   var statusHTML = '<ul class="bulleted">';
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i += 1) {

  statusHTML += '<li>';

  statusHTML += names[i].name;
  statusHTML += '</li>';
}
statusHTML += '</ul>';
document.getElementById('names').innerHTML = statusHTML;
  }
 };
  xhr.open('GET', 'data/names.json');
  xhr.send();
```

How would I do it to show only one name at a time? Not in a list like I did above?

Comment: So, you want to show random names from your list?

Comment: Fetch the data and bind a click event handler to the button. Keep an index variable (lets say `index`) starting with `0`. Every time the button is clicked you get the `index`'th item from the data and increment `index`. Think about what you want to do with you reach the end of the list.